# Simbolo € en plantilla de email en woocommerce no aparece

Tags: php, woocommerce

Al modificar/añadir la plantilla de woocomerce en el fichero email-order-items.php he borrado el simbolo del €.
El codigo es el siguiente y funciona correctamente a excepcion del €.

```
<td class="td" 
style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
  <?php
    echo wp_kses_post(
      $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), 
      array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) 
    ); 
  ?>
</td>
```

¿Como puedo corregir el codigo para que se coloque el simbolo del euro?

Las lineas de codigo se coloca a partir de la 74 en la plantilla original.

Comment: Probaste con `get_woocommerce_currency_symbol($order->get_currency() )` ?

Comment: No lo he probado , yno se como se implementaria en el codigo llevo menos de un mes con woocommerce.

Comment: Facil, en lugar de `$order->get_currency()`  pones lo que Yussef te dice y listo...

Comment: He realizado el cambio y me da error  <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), get_woocommerce_currency_symbol($order->get_currency() )); 
  </td>